# writing sql queries

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an sql query and I am having a problem. When we want to write a query with a where clause to narrow down our results, we can do

... where name = 'John'

(Where name is a column in the table).
Now I am trying to insert a clause like this except the name is "O'Malley". So I thought the query would be

... where name = 'O'Malley'

but this gives me a null pointer exception.
Does anyone know how you could solve this problem?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the single quote in the string "O'Malley" is interpreted by SQL as the string terminator. To escape a single quote, replace it with two single quotes, like this:

```
where name = 'O''Malley'
```

Edit: If the string "O'Malley" came from a user input, your code is vulnerable to an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) exploit. To avoid this risk, use a parameterized query.

Comment: @Richbits... it does produce "O'Malley" you know, single quote and all

Answer (score 2):

Use bind variables to avoid thinking about quotation problems.
Bind variables beware of sql injection to.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database you could escape the ' I think. Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use two apostrophes together in you search string SQL will realise that it is part of the string and isn't part of the SQL syntax.

```
where name = 'O''Malley'
```